# Get JSON Object from a nested JSON result

Tags: java, android, json, nested

I have the following JSON result:
This is a weather result.
My aim here is to get the cities names first.
then according to a city in the list, request a property

```
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "hourly": 1
  ,
  "lang": 1
  }
        , "results": [
        {
        "name": "Al-Arz",
        "city": "Al-Arz",
        "state": "",
        "country": "LB",
        "country_iso3166":"LB",
        "country_name":"Lebanon",
        "zmw": "00000.1.40105",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.1.40105"
        }
        ,
        {
        "name": "Beirut",
        "city": "Beirut",
        "state": "",
        "country": "LB",
        "country_iso3166":"LB",
        "country_name":"Lebanon",
        "zmw": "00000.1.40100",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.1.40100"
        }
        ,
        {
        "name": "Dahr Baidar",
        "city": "Dahr Baidar",
        "state": "",
        "country": "LB",
        "country_iso3166":"LB",
        "country_name":"Lebanon",
        "zmw": "00000.1.40110",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.1.40110"
        }
        ,
        {
        "name": "Houche-Al-Oumara",
        "city": "Houche-Al-Oumara",
        "state": "",
        "country": "LB",
        "country_iso3166":"LB",
        "country_name":"Lebanon",
        "zmw": "00000.1.40101",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.1.40101"
        }
        ,
        {
        "name": "Merdjayoun",
        "city": "Merdjayoun",
        "state": "",
        "country": "LB",
        "country_iso3166":"LB",
        "country_name":"Lebanon",
        "zmw": "00000.1.40104",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.1.40104"
        }
        ,
        {
        "name": "Rayack",
        "city": "Rayack",
        "state": "",
        "country": "LB",
        "country_iso3166":"LB",
        "country_name":"Lebanon",
        "zmw": "00000.1.40102",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.1.40102"
        }
        ,
        {
        "name": "Tripoli",
        "city": "Tripoli",
        "state": "",
        "country": "LB",
        "country_iso3166":"LB",
        "country_name":"Lebanon",
        "zmw": "00000.1.40103",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.1.40103"
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can i get the names of all cities?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject rootObject = (JSONObject)new JSONTokener(yourJsonString).nextValue();
JSONObject responseObject = rootObject.getJSONObject("response");
JSONArray cityArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("results");
List<String> listWithCityNames = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0; i< cityArray.lenght();i++){
  listWithCityNames.add(cityArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));

 }

for(String city:listWithCityNames){
   System.out.println(city);
 }
```

This snippet parses the json string in the var `yourJsonString` and collects the attribute `name` in the `results` array inside the `response` object of your json. Add `Try/Catch` blocks if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat it as a json object. Follow these steps

1. get this into a json object.
2. then take the value of "results" into one array using getString() method.
3. then take cast this result into a json array.
4. then iterate over the json array one by one ad using getString method you can get the values of all the cities.